# FragmentTransaction in ViewPager

Tags: android

I have a Viewpager with two fragments.
I want to replace each of the fragment with 3 different fragments.
How can I do this?
Also, can I change whole ArrayList with the new list of fragments after button click in the current fragment?

Here is what I've done.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_healthy_mode, container, false);

    swipeLeft = v.findViewById(R.id.leftSlide);
    swipeRight = v.findViewById(R.id.rightSlide);

    pageArray = new ArrayList<Fragment>();

    pageArray.add(new Female());
    pageArray.add(new Male());

 healthyModeAdapter = new HealthyModeAdapter(getFragmentManager(), pageArray);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.healthyModeViewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(healthyModeAdapter);


// I want to replace female n male fragment with 

    pageArray.add(new EctoBodyFemale());
    pageArray.add(new EndoBodyFemale());
    pageArray.add(new MesoBodyFemale());

    pageArray.add(new EctoBodyMale());
    pageArray.add(new EndoBodyMale());
    pageArray.add(new MesoBodyMale());
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewPager` supports operation with `View`s or `Fragment`s if I understand correctly you want each page each 3 sub components that are static, in such case you have 2 options:

Using nested fragments, create a `Fragment` for each page that will contain your sub-fragments. and use these parent fragments as the fragments your provide to the pager view

Note that nested fragments are not recommended, they have been proven to be buggy and might affect performances. So I suggest you to take the `View` approach, create an `xml` that defines the fragments, and after you inflate it provide it directly to the ViewPager.

Comment: Than you sir.    one more question, How can i change whole ArrayList with new list of fragments after button click in current fragment?

Comment: `ViewPager` works very similarly to `RecyclerView` you update your list that is used by your adapter, and invoke `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter